# Convert Check box boolean value to string in BIRT 4.1?

Tags: sql, oracle, checkbox, birt

In BIRT, How to cast the check box boolean report parameter to string value so string value can be passed to report sql parameter query from oracle database?  Thanks.

Comment: You can modify your SQL query using CASE option.

Comment: @kazik1616 I think, Oracle 10g does not support boolean datatype in sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a default value expression instead of linking this query parameter to a report parameter, as shown below. For example if we want to set "0" when false and "1" when true use an expression like

```
params["myBooleanCheckbox"].value==null || !params["myBooleanCheckbox"].value?"0":"1";
```

[image]